# Why is this string slicing not working as desired

Tags: python, arrays

Leetcode question:
You are given two integer arrays nums1 and nums2, sorted in non-decreasing order, and two integers m and n, representing the number of elements in nums1 and nums2 respectively.

Merge nums1 and nums2 into a single array sorted in non-decreasing order.

The final sorted array should not be returned by the function, but instead be stored inside the array nums1. To accommodate this, nums1 has a length of m + n, where the first m elements denote the elements that should be merged, and the last n elements are set to 0 and should be ignored. nums2 has a length of n.

My solution

```
class Solution:
    def merge(self, nums1: List[int], m: int, nums2: List[int], n: int) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
        """
        nums1 = nums1[:m]
        nums1+=nums2
        nums1.sort()
```

Input:

```
nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0]
m = 3
nums2 = [2,5,6]
n = 3
```

Output

```
[1,2,3,0,0,0]
```

Expected

```
[1,2,2,3,5,6]
```

This should work just fine...dont know what is the syntactical error.

Comment: Obligatory reading: [Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html) and [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). Why do you think there's a "syntactical error"? What does your debugging tell you?

Comment: you should return `nums1` or print it, and not `List` is `list` of type hinting.

Comment: What does this have to do with string slicing? You don't have any strings, you have lists.

Comment: `nums1 = nums1[:m]` assigns the local variable with a new list. So nothing after tha modifies the caller's list.

Comment: @Barmar I think it's answer to question, if question is "why"

Comment: @AbdullahSaidAbdeaaziz the point of the exercise is to mutate the list in place, not return a new list. As soon as the OP does `nums1 = xyz`, all hope is lost.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
nums1[m:] = nums2
nums1.sort()
print(nums1)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```